# Question Regarding a $\mathbb{Q}$-Automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, i)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha, i) \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ under field inclusion s.t. $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$.  Let $\sigma \in G(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,i), \mathbb{Q})$.  In case it's relevant, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, i)$ is meant to be the splitting field for $p(x)= x^4 - 2$.

Now why must it be that $\sigma(\alpha) = \alpha$ or $\sigma(\alpha) = - \alpha$?

I understand that $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms are possible in both cases.  But I don't understand why $\sigma(\alpha) = \alpha i$ -- as an example -- would lead to a contradiction.

Comment: What makes you think $\sigma$ can't be $\alpha i$?

Comment: I meant, $\sigma(\alpha)$ --- why can't it be $\alpha i$?

Comment: Earth to Loose: come in, please.

Comment: Author unresponsive to comments. Question apparently abandoned. 

Answer (score 0):

It does not lead to a contradiction because if $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,i)$ is the splitting field of $x^4-2$ , it contains all the ceros of $x^4-2$, and every isomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,i)$ to a sub-field of $\mathbb{C}$, maps $\alpha$ to a conjugate, in that way, there is an isomorphism that maps $\alpha$ to $i\alpha$.

Now, because $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,i)$ contains all the ceros of $x^4-2$ , the isomorphism that maps $\alpha$ to $i\alpha$ must be an automorphism.

In fact, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,i)$ is a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ , then every isomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,i)$ to a sub-field of $\mathbb{C}$ is actually and automorphism.

So it is posible to have $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha i$